# Set width for an object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem, I want to set the width for an object using jquery, My object

```
<object id="game" width="960" height="560" style="visibility: visible; width: 0px;">
```

So I want to set width : 960 --> 0
I tried like this but not work :

```
document.getElementById("game").width = "0px";
```

Can you help me please? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
$('#game').width(0);
```

It sets width to number of pixels specified by parameter. You can also use strings like '0px' or other units like '%'. [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can use:

```
document.getElementById("game").style.width = "0px";
```

You need to use the `style` property and then you can set the width and not directly.

Using jquery you can use the following code:

```
$("#game").width(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this jQuery:

```
$("#game").attr("width", "0px");
```